# Upgrade from gradle 8.0.2 to 8.1.0 breaks GitHub builds

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio Giraffe I switched from gradle 8.0.2 to 8.1.0 as recommended. It seems to be working fine when building from Android Studio on Windows 11 but it [broke my GitHub builds](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/actions/runs/5701784677/job/15452828352#step:5:613).

Here is the error apparently:

```
ERROR: /home/runner/work/Fulguris/Fulguris/app/build/intermediates/merged_java_res/slionsFullDownloadRelease/base.jar: R8: com.android.tools.r8.ResourceException: com.android.tools.r8.internal.Tb: I/O exception while reading '/home/runner/work/Fulguris/Fulguris/app/build/intermediates/merged_java_res/slionsFullDownloadRelease/base.jar': /home/runner/work/Fulguris/Fulguris/app/build/intermediates/merged_java_res/slionsFullDownloadRelease/base.jar
```

Not exactly obvious what that is…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See https://issuetracker.google.com/277166577#comment6 for the resolution of this issue.

To fix it just replace `whenTaskAdded` by `configureEach` in your gradle file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing if I had attempted a release build from Android Studio it would have failed too.

Comment: I fixed it there: https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/commit/cadbac121d4eb18abf995ec32b3fd449cb570ab8